# What's a word for "looking for something to do"

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word (or short phrase) with a more positive connotation than "bored", meaning I am actively trying to find something to do.

If context helps, I'm thinking of a scenario along the lines of "I have nothing to do for the weekend, but I want to do something so I am "????".

Any thoughts?  The closest I can think of is "Itchy feet", but that is more related specifically to travelling.

Comment: So I am itchy feet?

Comment: "at loose ends" is an idiom expressing this idea, although not the adventure-seeking aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ***itching for something to do*** you can use the adjective ***restless***. From Cambridge Dictionaries:

> [**restless**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/restless)
>   moving because you are unable to relax, esp. because you are worried or bored . . . .
>   Restless can also mean not satisfied with your situation and wanting a change

And the idiom, from MacMillan Dictionaries:

> [**be itching for something/to do something**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-itching-for-something-to-do-something)
>   to feel very impatient because you want to do something immediately

The idiom is most often used when you already know what it is you want to do—the MacMillan example is "*itching to get into the kitchen*" and your own "itchy feet" is very similar to phrases like *itching to get out of the house* or *itching to travel*—but you can stick with the even vaguer "something" if you are just generally bored and restless, modifying it as appropriate.

So for your example, you could say:

> I have nothing to do for the weekend, but I want to do something so I am **restless**.

or just

> I am **itching to do something** (exciting/new/different) this weekend.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as it is closest to what I am looking for, however I still think it has a slightly "negative" connotation.  It's set me down a good train of thought though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions, which may help you to find a short phrase to express what you're looking for:

- energized
- motivated
- curious
- interested
- open

Wanting to do something but not knowing what to do leads to exploration and discovery, so perhaps these fit your bill:

- exploration
- discovery

I hope these help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> **Seeking an adventure**

---

> **adventure**
>
> noun
>
> 1. a risky undertaking of unknown outcome
> 2. **an exciting or
>    unexpected event or course of events**
> 3. a hazardous financial operation; commercial speculation
>
> [Reverso Dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/adventure%20seeking)

---

This phrase directly relates to what you are actively doing, rather than how you are feeling.

Answer (score 0):

**trolling**

[101 Ways You Can Help](https://books.google.com/books?id=CG6bElTz7AUC&pg=PA83&dq=beach%20%22trolling%20for%20something%20to%20do%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhy9jZ26TVAhWH2T4KHb49DvcQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=beach%20%22trolling%20for%20something%20to%20do%22&f=false):

> Heading to the beach? The movies? A science museum with a great exhibit on dinosaurs? Or just out trolling for something to do in the minivan?

Answer (score 0):

> **Antsy**
> [ant-see]
> /adjective, Informal.
>
> 1. unable to sit or stand still; fidgety.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/antsy)